# Can a VQC initial weight be custom initialized?

Tags: qiskit

I am following the tutorial from https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-machine-learning/tutorials/02_neural_network_classifier_and_regressor.html

```
# construct feature map, ansatz, and optimizer
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(num_inputs)
ansatz = RealAmplitudes(num_inputs, reps=1)

# construct variational quantum classifier
vqc = VQC(
    feature_map=feature_map,
    ansatz=ansatz,
    loss="cross_entropy",
    optimizer=COBYLA(maxiter=30),
    callback=callback_graph,
)

# callback function that draws a live plot when the .fit() method is called
def callback_graph(weights, obj_func_eval):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    objective_func_vals.append(obj_func_eval)
    plt.title("Objective function value against iteration")
    plt.xlabel("Iteration")
    plt.ylabel("Objective function value")
    plt.plot(range(len(objective_func_vals)), objective_func_vals)
    plt.show()
```

I am attempting to initialize my own weights for the `vqc`, but I failed to identify anything in documentation helps as per https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.VQC.html#vqc

How can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `initial_point` defines the starting point of the ansatz parameters (weights) for the optimization. There are examples in the test case here if that's of help https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-machine-learning/blob/main/test/algorithms/classifiers/test_vqc.py

Comment: Hi, I have a quick test with the solution provided, I think it works.

Comment: So in the documentation mentioned it as `initial_point` as well, is that a common terminology in quantum machine learning?